# JavaScript if statement trouble

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

My javascript is suppose to add value to a price variable and then return the price, my trouble is that i am using a select option and when i have more than one the price will only use the id of the last if statement, here is my HTML;

```
<form>
    <select>
    <option name ="Bristol "value="40.0" id ="BN1">Bristol - Newcastle</option>
    <option name ="London "value="35.0" id ="BL1">Bristol - London</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="BookingFare(); return false;">Submit</button><br>
    </form>
    <label id='priceBox'></label>
```

and here is my Javascript

```
function BookingFare() {
        var price = 0;
        //var ofAdults = getElementById('adults').value;
        //var ofChildren = getElementById('children').value;
        var BN1 = document.getElementById('BN1').value;
        var BL1 = document.getElementById('BL1').value;

        if (BL1) {
         var price = BL1;
        }
        if (BN1) {
         var price = BN1; 
        }
        document.getElementById('priceBox').innerHTML = price;
        }
```

So basically the program will return the price of BN1, even if i choose Bristol - London. 
Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Your code doesn't check to see which of the options is actually selected.  You can tell that by checking the "selected" property of the DOM nodes you've fetched.

Comment: Unless your option elements need IDs, ditch them, and grab the value of the select instead (give that an ID if needed).

Comment: price is a local variable in if satement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result makes sense. The check inside your ifs is truey in both cases (probably because both BL1, BN1 exist).

What you need to do in your code is retrieve the selected index and then use it.

Give an id to your dropdown list:

```
<select id="dropdownList">
....
```

And then use it in your code to retrieve the selected value:

```
var dropdownList = document.getElementById("dropdownList");
var price = dropdownList.options[dropdownList.selectedIndex].value;
//rest of code
```

Take a look on a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript).
You can also find a relative tutorial [here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-select.phtml).

Comment: This explains what is happening but does not help in solving the question at hand.

Comment: Give me a minute to complete my thought.

Comment: Oh so you're one of these people: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Comment: Also, a tutorial: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-select.phtml

Comment: @JoeFrambach Still learning SO, but the point is I am trying to find a balance between being fast but post good quality answers. Sorry for this, it indeed contained no clue to the answer which is unacceptable.

Comment: Thankyou very much it has worked, and also thankyou for the relative links to further help!

Answer (score 0):

1st: You are defining the variable *price* multiple times.
2nd: Your code checks for 'value' and of cause, it always has a value.
I guess, what you really want to check is, whether an option is selected or not annd then use its value.

```js
function BookingFare() {
  var price = 0;
  var BN1 = document.getElementById('BN1');
  var BL1 = document.getElementById('BL1');

  if (BL1.selected) {
    price = BL1.value;
  }
  if (BN1.selected) {
    price = BN1.value;
  }
  document.getElementById('priceBox').innerHTML = price;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select>
    <option name="Bristol " value="40.0" id="BN1">Bristol - Newcastle</option>
    <option name="London " value="35.0" id="BL1">Bristol - London</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" onclick="BookingFare(); return false;">Submit</button>
  <br>
  <label id='priceBox'></label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```html
<script>
    function BookingFare() {
        var price = 0;
        //var ofAdults = getElementById('adults').value;
        //var ofChildren = getElementById('children').value;
        var bristol = document.getElementById('bristol').value;
        console.log(bristol);
        if (bristol == 35.0) {
         var price = bristol;
        }
        if (bristol == 40.0) {
         var price = bristol; 
        }
        document.getElementById('priceBox').innerHTML = price;
}
</script>
<form>
    <select id="bristol">
    <option name ="Bristol "value="40.0" id ="BN1">Bristol - Newcastle</option>
    <option name ="London "value="35.0" id ="BL1">Bristol - London</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="BookingFare(); return false;">Submit</button>
</form>
<label id='priceBox'></label>
```